# How to make a leading token optional in a RegexNER expression?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I have a very simple use case where I need to add an NER annotation to a sequence of two words where the first word is optional.
For example, I need to annotate both "net income" and "income" phrases as a same NE type.

With ordinary regular expressions the following expression works:

```
([Nn]et\s)?[Ii]ncome
```

However, in RegexNER it does not work. 
The effect that the above regex has in RegexNER is that the word "income" is annotated in both sequences, but the word "net" is not annotated in the sequence "net income", which is not the result that I need.


That is sort of expected, knowing that RegexNER matches a sequence of regular expressions over a sequence of tokens, not a single regular expression over a single string.
However, the following syntax does not work either:

```
([Nn]et)? [Ii]ncome
```

The effect that this expression has is that the sequence "net income" is annotated entirely, but just "income" is not annotated at all.
This is unexpected, since this seems like a very simple use case.
I tried different ways to denote the initial token as a group and also tried different quantifiers - it still does not work.


Any help with making the first token optional will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer my own question. This is not a direct solution, it's a workaround.
The following expression will work, but only with **TokensRegex**, not with RegexNER:
`/[Nn]et/? /[Ii]ncome/`

I am not sure why this is the case, maybe RegexNER does not support quantifiers at the token level the same way TokensRegex does.

Comment: I had a similar issue with CoreNLP 3.8.0. I have a feeling that `? operator` does not work in `RegexNER`. I tried `?` with the 1st token and also with a token between two other two tokens and none worked. For the time being my solution to this problem is duplicating the rules :-(